# I would like to simplify SSH Tunneling to do a MySQL Dump and SCP the file to local machine

Tags: ssh, mysql, scp, ssh-tunnel

Server setup (fake IPs)

- utility - 1.1.1.1 - SSH access on public IP
- database2 - 1.1.1.2 - SSH access on private IP from utility

On a semi-regular basis I need to do a mysqldump on database2 and pull that down to my local machine so I can debug our app with real data.  My current process is as follows:

- ssh into utility
- ssh into database2
- execute mysqldump command
- exit from database2
- scp dump file down to utility
- exit utility
- scp dump file down to local machine

Needless to say this is not optimal.  Is there a quicker method, possibly via tunneling, that I could use given my setup?

Answer (score 0):

you can

1. make dump by cron on database2
2. make port forward on utility and connect at once to database2

summary: you will get dump by one scp command.

UPD:

if you can't port forward or cron, you can add access to database from utility and make mysqldump from him.

Comment: I don't really want to run a cron.  When I do a mysqldump I really just want a specific snapshot at that given time.  Also, I'd appreciate more detailed answers.  I'm not a sysadmin and help in what commands to run would be best.  As in examples.

Comment: @Gregg, which OS/firewall on utility?