# mysqldump via SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, backup, mysql, tunneling

I have a server setup as follows:

- `webserver` (gateway machine, accessible from the Internet via SSH)
- `dbserver` (database server, *not accessible from the web*)

My goal is to use `mysqldump` to pull a backup from `dbserver` to my laptop via the web.  Up to this point, the question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322352/i-would-like-to-simplify-ssh-tunneling-to-do-a-mysql-dump-and-scp-the-file-to-lo), *except* that `webserver` does *not* have `mysqldump` installed, and I don't have the rights to install it.  So I'm trying to use `mysqldump` on my laptop to pull from a server behind a gateway that I don't have SSH rights to.

Following the discussions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/134007/how-to-dump-remote-database-without-mysqldump) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/36467/temporary-ssh-tunnel-for-backup-purposes), I'm trying to do something like this to set up the tunnel:

```
ssh -f -L 3306:dbserver:3306 user@webserver -N
```

followed by:

```
mysqldump -P 3306 -h localhost -u dbuser -p db
```

but I run into the same trouble [this person](https://serverfault.com/questions/134007/how-to-dump-remote-database-without-mysqldump) did, and am not quite sure what's going on with the tunneling or how to fix it (and adding an entry to my laptop's hosts file doesn't seem to fix it like it did for him).

Answer (score 0):

Dump databases daily to the gateway machine then fetch from there

```
#!/bin/sh
# Backup the mysql Databases
 for database in $(mysql -u b4ckup -pd1psh1t --host server.database.net -e "show databases" | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v Database)
do
        mysqldump -u user -p password --lock-tables=false --host server.database.net $database > /storage/backups/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date +\%A`/server/$database.sql
done
```

Comment: mysqldump is not installed on the gateway machine.

Comment: you are calling the dump on the mysql server box

Comment: Got it.  +1, but I wasn't clear enough: I do not have SSH access to the dbserver machine _at all_, so I have no way to invoke mysqldump directly on the dbserver.

Thus my attempt to use my local mysqldump instance, but I have to pass through the gateway to do so.

This would all be so simple if my university still allowed VPN access to non-faculty >.<